# how to install windows phone SDK 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, installation

I am trying to install Windows Phone 7 SDK on my PC which has a Windows 7 Home Premium operating system.
I tried to install the software, but I got an error that I don't have the Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1. I installed the Service Pack but I still can't install the Windows Phone SDK. Does It have to do with the fact that my OS is "home premium"? Or is there any other reason there should be a problem?

Comment: Is it WP7 or WP8 you are trying to install ? WP8 does not supportWindows 7 OS. For Windows Phone 7.1 you will need at least a Win 7 Professional Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows Vista
Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 – all editions except Starter EditionWindows 7 (x86 and x64) – all editions except Starter Edition
Installation requires 4 GB of free disk space on the system drive.
3 GB RAMWindows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver. Pleasereadthis: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

Answer (score 1):

Go here and download visual studio express 2010 for windows phone. This should be the complete package of what you need

You cant just download the SDK without visual studios

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads